# How do I fix/prevent Data Overwriting Issue in Web Scrape Loop?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, web-scraping, overwrite

I was able to loop the web scraping process, but the data collected from the page that comes after replaces the data from the page before. Making the excel contains only the data from the last page. What do I need to do?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
print ('all imported successfuly')


for x in range(1, 44):
    link = (f'https://www.trustpilot.com/review/birchbox.com?page={x}')
    print (link)
    req = requests.get(link)
    content = req.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
    names = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'consumer-information__name'})
    headers = soup.find_all('h2', attrs={'class':'review-content__title'})
    bodies = soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class':'review-content__text'})
    ratings = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'star-rating star-rating--medium'})
    dates = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'review-content-header__dates'})


print ('pass1')

df = pd.DataFrame({'User Name': names, 'Header': headers, 'Body': bodies, 'Rating': ratings, 'Date': dates})
df.to_csv('birchbox006.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
print ('excel done')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using a loop the variables are being constantly overwritten. Normally what you'd do in a situation like this is have an array and then append to it throughout the loop:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
print ('all imported successfuly')

# Initialize an empty dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
for x in range(1, 44):
    names = []
    headers = []
    bodies = []
    ratings = []  
    published = []
    updated = []
    reported = []

    link = (f'https://www.trustpilot.com/review/birchbox.com?page={x}')
    print (link)
    req = requests.get(link)
    content = req.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
    articles = soup.find_all('article', {'class':'review'})
    for article in articles:
        names.append(article.find('div', attrs={'class': 'consumer-information__name'}).text.strip())
        headers.append(article.find('h2', attrs={'class':'review-content__title'}).text.strip())
        try:
            bodies.append(article.find('p', attrs={'class':'review-content__text'}).text.strip())
        except:
            bodies.append('')

        try:
            ratings.append(article.find('p', attrs={'class':'review-content__text'}).text.strip())
        except:
            ratings.append('')
        dateElements = article.find('div', attrs={'class':'review-content-header__dates'}).text.strip()

        jsonData = json.loads(dateElements)
        published.append(jsonData['publishedDate'])
        updated.append(jsonData['updatedDate'])
        reported.append(jsonData['reportedDate'])


    # Create your temporary dataframe of the first iteration, then append that into your "final" dataframe
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'User Name': names, 'Header': headers, 'Body': bodies, 'Rating': ratings, 'Published Date': published, 'Updated Date':updated, 'Reported Date':reported})
    df = df.append(temp_df, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)

print ('pass1')


df.to_csv('birchbox006.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
print ('excel done')
```

Comment: I tried running this code but only got back 43 lines of data in the excel. Do you happen to know why this happens?

Comment: Oh wait. It's not just 43 rows of data. Each row has a whole collection of data from one page within it. This works perfectly. Now I just need to sort the data in the excel. Thank you so much!

Comment: @SaraJitkresorn try again

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if it's possible to somehow tweak your code abit such that the data collected are put in separate cells? Right now the excel file generated by the code compiles all comments from the same page into one single cell and I could not find a way to efficiently separate them into multiple cells of their own since there are multiple commas in the comments.

Comment: I just saw that you edited your code. And now the code works exactly the way I wanted it to be. Thank you again. I have no prior knowledge to programming so people from this site has helped me tremendously!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to store that data after each iteration somewhere. Theres a few ways you can do it. You can just store everythin in a list, then create your dataframe. Or what I did is create a "temporary" dataframe that is created after each iteration, then append that into the final dataframe. Think of it like bailing water. You have a small bucket of water, to then empty into a large bucket, that will collect/hold all the water you are trying to collect.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
print ('all imported successfuly')

# Initialize an empty dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
for x in range(1, 44):
    published = []
    updated = []
    reported = []

    link = (f'https://www.trustpilot.com/review/birchbox.com?page={x}')
    print (link)
    req = requests.get(link)
    content = req.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
    names = [ x.text.strip() for x in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'consumer-information__name'})]
    headers = [ x.text.strip() for x in soup.find_all('h2', attrs={'class':'review-content__title'})]
    bodies = [ x.text.strip() for x in soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class':'review-content__text'})]
    ratings = [ x.text.strip() for x in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'star-rating star-rating--medium'})]
    dateElements = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'review-content-header__dates'})
    for date in dateElements:
        jsonData = json.loads(date.text.strip())
        published.append(jsonData['publishedDate'])
        updated.append(jsonData['updatedDate'])
        reported.append(jsonData['reportedDate'])


    # Create your temporary dataframe of the first iteration, then append that into your "final" dataframe
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'User Name': names, 'Header': headers, 'Body': bodies, 'Rating': ratings, 'Published Date': published, 'Updated Date':updated, 'Reported Date':reported})
    df = df.append(temp_df, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)

print ('pass1')


df.to_csv('birchbox006.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
print ('excel done')
```

Comment: I tried running your code but got this.
 File "C:/Users/Sara Jitkresorn/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/StackOverflow.py", line 21, in <module>
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'User Name': names, 'Header': headers, 'Body': bodies, 'Rating': ratings, 'Date': dates})

Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: oh might be because it's beautifulsoup elements. I also see that the lists don't all have same length. Give me a minute, I'll fix this

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you are overwriting your variables in each iteration.
If you want to extend this variables, you can do for example:

```
names = []
bodies = []
ratings = []
dates = []
for x in range(1, 44):
    link = (f'https://www.trustpilot.com/review/birchbox.com?page={x}')
    print (link)
    req = requests.get(link)
    content = req.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
    names += soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'consumer-information__name'})
    headers += soup.find_all('h2', attrs={'class':'review-content__title'})
    bodies += soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class':'review-content__text'})
    ratings += soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'star-rating star-rating--medium'})
    dates += soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'review-content-header__dates'})
```